# Can applications developed using salesforce1 be sold with custom branding?

Tags: salesforce1-app, mobile

I have a set of basic questions on mobile app development in SF.

I see that a lot of things can be done using salesforce1. Is it possible that i can make these customizations and sell this as package . Can we package the development made using salesforce1 and sell as an app in google play?

Can partner users access partner records using REST API? If i want to build an app for partner users what are my options? Does salesforce support this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't sell the functionality on Google Play with Salesforce1.Salesforce1 is itself a Play store app. You need to launch your app on Appexchange ,Users will be able to access the application using Salesforce1 app. 
You can build a functionality on Android platform using available Salesforce Sdks  and sell it using Google Play.

Comment: Thanks @Sagar.. so it would mean that the user would have to go through salesforce1 app and the customization i made would be available for his/her organization if they purchased it through the app store

Comment: If the user installed your appexchange app in their organization then he/she can access your functionality using the Salesforce1 app.